# SSO for sharepoint 2010 and asp.net app using adfs

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity

I was tasked with creating an SSO solution from an existing asp.net app to a new sharepoint 2010 app.
The existing asp.net app uses forms authentication, but not against a single data source. It checks a database, active directory and a few mainframe tables to authenticate, and finally creates a forms authentication ticket.

I was looking to share the token between sp2010 and the asp.net app, but I am now realizing this is not possible, due to the fact the sp2010 does not use simple FBA tokens any more.

So now I am looking to go the STS and claims-based route. After looking in to it a little, I understand that using ADFS would be much better than building a custom STS for the asp.net side. My issue is that since I have the custom ticket creation authentication method on the asp.net side, I don't have a single data source to "feed" the adfs. I am new to sharepoint and adfs and I really don't know how to begin this type of integration.

Can anyone help me get my head around this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADFS attribute stores might solve your problem, although for this to make sense you would ideally integrate Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) into your application, which might be an intrusive change.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-help-attribute-stores(v=ws.10).aspx

In short, ADFS is not limited to AD for collecting user data. You can configure it to query other user attribute stores, such as your database. You can then author rules within ADFS to tell it what queries to make, and ADFS will use these queries to populate user claims into the token that ADFS issues to your application.